# You need to provide a parserOptions.project for Eslint

Tags: typescript, babeljs, eslint

we are trying to setup Typescript in our JS code base. We are doing this step by step, so we are trying to adapt our eslint configuration to work at the same time for both JS and TS files at the same time.

Right now this is our [configuration](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/antoniogamizbadger/f5cd2328ff276aff515aeec79099c402/raw/e3537e10da61e81dcda037af2e638ce9f157b5b9/.eslintrc). With this config, our TS files work perfectly fine without any errors. The problem is when we open JS files because we get this error:

```
Error: Error while loading rule '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': 
You have used a rule which requires parserServices to be generated. 
You must therefore provide a value for the "parserOptions.project" property for @typescript-eslint/parser.
```

Not sure why I'm getting this error because we have specified that property in the eslint configuration and it's working fine.

Any idea how to fix the problem? Thanks!

**Update**

This is our tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./web/**/*.ts", "./web/**/*.tsx"
  ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules", "**/*.js", "dist"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What happens if in your eslintrc you change your root parser to: `"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"`? My project also has mixed ts/js, and we have our parser set as "@typescript-eslint/parser" for everything, but only our ts-specific file override rules has `project: ['./tsconfig.json']`